# Infinitely generated modules with weirdly jumping ranks

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Assume we have a commutative Noetherian ring $R$ with a unit and a connected spectrum and a module $M$ over it. The following is known:

1. $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ has a finite stratification (in the sense of Stacks [052F](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/052F)) by locally closed subschemes such that the restriction of $M$ to each stratum is locally free of finite rank.
2. When we pass to lower-dimensional stratum, the rank of $M$ becomes strictly less.

If the stratification is non-trivial then $M$ is *not* finitely generated (indeed, it would be simultaneously [upper semi-continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2056126/691994) and lower semi-continuous so constant).

My question is: do such modules arise naturally in some areas of mathematics?

Not to be empty-handed, here are some examples:

- If $R$ is a DVR take $M=Frac(R)$ and the stratification is {generic point, closed point).
- Let $k$ be a finite field on $q$ elements. Consider the ring $R=k[[s]][t]$. Take the stratification {$\mathrm{Spec}(k((s))[t])$, $\mathrm{Spec}(R/(s))$}. $M$ is the (noncommutative) ring of polynomials on a single variable $\tau$ and with coefficients in $k[[s]]$, with the multiplication rule $\tau\times\alpha=\alpha^q\times\tau$ for any $\alpha\in k[[s]]$. Then let $k[[s]]$ act on $M$ by multiplication from the left and let $t$ act by multiplying from the right by $\tau+s\tau^2$. It is easy to compute that $M$ on the general stratum has rank 2 and on the special stratum it has rank 1.